# How to use value from one cell into another cell's "Conditional format rules "

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to set Conditional format rule on cell Y1 based on value of cell X1.

e.g. If Y1 cell value > value in X1 then set particular color.

But I am not getting which formula to use to get value from X1 cell

Answer (score 0):

### Simply use `=X1` with the format rule `greater than`:

[image]

---

- The important point is to to use `=` to indicate that you are refering to a cell in the spreadsheet.
- See also [Use conditional formatting rules in Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#zippy=%2Cuse-custom-formulas-with-conditional-formatting)

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this:

```
=Y1>X1
```

[image]